# Наложение водяного знака на уже имеющиеся изображение

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Каким образом можно наложить водяной знак(изображение), на уже имеющиеся изображения. 
Эти изображения вставлены на сайте через **img src**, и добавить новые блоки нет возможности, или обернуть изображение в еще один блок тоже не вариант.
Я думаю с помощью css это как-то сделать. Я понимаю что в таком случае при скачивании изображения водяной знак не останется, но этого и не нужно. Просто на сайте чтоб был. 
Дело в том что изображения все разных размеров. Как определить позиции наложения водяного знака в таком случае? Предположим что нужно поставить его внизу справа.
Буду благодарен за любую полезную информацию.

Comment: это уже не водяной знак тогда )

Comment: Ну да)) чтоб понятнее было так назвал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нет возможности обернуть каждое изображение в дополнительный блок, тогда как вариант

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").find('img').wrap('<div class="wrap-img"></div>');
});
```

```css
.wrap-img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
.wrap-img > img {
  display: block;
}
.wrap-img:before {
  content: 'Logo';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  background: tomato;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/60x50" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/80x100" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/60x50" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/80x100" alt="">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо! А изображение вместо надписи таким образом можно вставить?

Comment: да https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/s7g7md7e/

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант: наложить фоновую картинку, она же водяной знак на блок с картинкой.

```
<div class="block"><img class="watermark" src="image.jpg" alt="" /></div>
```

css

```
.block {
  background: url(watermark.jpg) right bottom no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```